# Ubuntu 14.10 recognizes, but does not show the USB stick

Tags: usb, 14.10, usb-drive

I have a problem when connecting my pen drive in Ubuntu 14.10. I've already tested the two USB ports (2.0 and 3.0), and ubuntu recognizes, however shows no window / option to show me what's in the pen drive.

Previously, he was with old version of Ubuntu (boot). Soon after I format it, the trouble started. I've already formatted with the three options available, but none of them, after I disconnect / reconnect, shows me an option that allows me to add files on that disc.

Searching the internet, I found similar situations, but that did not resolve my problem. The vast majority said to execute commands like *dmesg*, *lsusb* or *fdisk -l*, where the only unusual thing I found was:

```
[sdb] No Caching mode page found
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I will be grateful to those who know the problem or give me a hint how I can solve it. Feel free to request additional information as well.

Here is the output of lsblk:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 692.8G  0 part / 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP] 
sdb      8:16   1  14.7G  0 disk 
sr0      11:0   1  1024M  0 rom
```

*Sorry for my bad English...*

Comment: Please post the output of  `lsblk`.

Comment: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698,7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 692,8G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   5,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14,7G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: Thanks, do you have any data stored on the drive or is it blank?

Comment: No, I don't, but I want store some files.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how problem it could be?

Comment: I think we can do something to fix it whatever it may be. Does it not show up in your filemanager?

Comment: No, that's the problem. When I go to "disks", it shows the pen drive, with all configurations correct. But it doesn't open any window or anything to me. I've already saw the removable media (on details), but nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the `mkdir` command to `sudo mkdir` instead.

Comment: also, I added an extra command for write permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, open a terminal and execute the following command:**

```
nautilus /media/$USER/ &
```

Nautilus should open and on the left, the USB device should be listed as "15.0 GB Volume". Click on "15.0 GB Volume" to open the device.

---

**If the device does not show up in nautilus, you can manually mount the drive.**

Open a terminal and execute the following commands.

First, create a mount-point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER/usb0
```

Next, mount the device:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/$USER/usb0
```

Then, open the USB device using nautilus:

```
nautilus /media/$USER/usb0 &
```

---

**Finally, you will need to change ownership to allow write permission:**

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER/usb0
```

Please post any errors, thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Okay let's format the device before mounting:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb
```

If it complains, just press enter and ignore it unless it tells you to use -I. If you need to use -I option, you can do so like this.

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 -I /dev/sdb
```

When formatting is done, try mounting the device:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/$USER/usb0
```

You may need to unplug and plug the device back in again if it doesn't work at first.

If successfull, don't forget to chown the device:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER/usb0
```

Comment: No, I still have the problem. When I put "nautilus /media/$USER/ &" the first time, a window opened, but the USB wasn't listed (it was an HD Directory - the properties showed a size of 670 GB).  Well, then I created the mount-point, and the error was when I mount the device - which didn't happen.  Here is the error:  lucas@lucas:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/$USER/usb0
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: I put dmesg, it had this output:  [  621.017953] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  621.017957] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  621.039773]  sdb:
[  621.041004] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  791.483251] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DWBL] (Node f2c27288), AE_AML_UNINITIALIZED_ELEMENT (20140424/psparse-536)

Comment: @LucasLopesLisboa I've updated the answer with a reformat.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked perfectly. I used the command "sudo mkfs -t ext4 / dev / sdb" and then the window appeared. The other commands are not required. Thank you. Just as an observation, after formatting in ext4, I had to use the command "sudo chown -R $ USER: $ USER / media / $ USER / usb0" to be able to write in pen drive.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LucasLopesLisboa whoops, thanks for pointing that out,

Comment: yes, the reformat worked also for a new fat32, for some reason the pre-formated vanilla fat32 was undetectable by nautilus, it is for a bootable ubuntu live pendrive